# Use multiple delimiters with awk and keep track of $0 as var to sort different fields

Tags: macos, sorting, awk

i've tried to solve this problem with awk, i could do it with python but i want an awk solution.

i have an input file which looks like this:

```
XXXX;XXXXX;XXXXXXX;XXXX;XX_2018_01_10_XXX_XXX_XX
```

I would like to get the data format : 2018_01_10

I know to do this way :

```
cat my_file.txt | awk -F ';' '{print $5}' | awk -F '_' '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4}'
```

though through piping i'm losing the original $0 : `XXXX;XXXXX;XXXXXXX;XXXX;XX_2018_01_10_XXX_XXX_XX`

i haven't found any solution to this, and i don't know what would be the best solution to this. The final purpose of this is to sort all my data by date, with sort. By example:

```
sort -n -t'_' -k1 -k2 -k3
```

for now i have this command line :

```
cat my_file.txt | awk -F ';' '{print $5}' | awk -F '_' '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4}' | sort -n -t'_' -k1 -k2 -k3
```

but my output is only the date:

```
2018_08_17
2018_08_28
```

when i would like to get this :

```
XXXX;XXXXX;XXXXXXX;XXXX;XX_2018_08_17_XXX_XXX_XX
XXXX;XXXXX;XXXXXXX;XXXX;XX_2018_08_28_XXX_XXX_XX
```

Hope i'm clear enough...

**edit :**

the number of X in each fields delimited by ';' is not always the same.
I have an other problem : in the fields containing the date, i can have sometimes 1 or 2 '_' before the date, example :

```
XXXX;XXXXX;XXXXXXX;XXXX;X_2017_10_18 ## here there is only 1 '_'
XXXX;XXXXX;XXXXXXX;XXXX;XXXX_XXXX_2017_07_12 ## here there is 2 '_'
```

Comment: You probably want a Schwartzian Transform. So, using `awk` you would extract the date and pre-pend it to the start of every record as a new field, then sort by the new first field (using `sort`), then remove it again (using `awk`).

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about `XX_2018_01_10_XXX`. Can the `X` be letters or digits or underscores? Are there always exactly two `X`s before and 3-3-2 after the date?

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for your answer. I've already thought about this, but I still have the same problem to track the original input line $0. Yes the X can be letter or digits, and no there is no always exactly the same number of X in every fields...

Comment: otherwise i could extract the date into a new file, then paste the newfile and my original input file to get what i want... but i thought i could do the whole thing into an awk command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below AWK construct to do this :-

```
awk -F ";" 'match($5, /(.*)_([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2})(.*)/, ary) {print ary[2], $0}' my_file.txt | sort | awk '{print $2}'
```

Explanation  :-

`match($5, /(.*)_([0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2})(.*)/, ary)` will match field 5 as regular expression

Prefix date i.e. `ary[2]` before every line i.e. `$0` .

Sort it. And then extract the full line which now will be `$2` .

Comment: It's almost working, though i can't use the `substr($5, 4, 10)` cause the string length before the date is not always the same length...

Comment: since i'm on macos i had to install gawk, looks like the match regex isn't working with awk on mac... though it's working ! thanks !

Comment: You should mention this is gawk-only for the 3rd arg to match()

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
awk -F';' '{split($5,a,"_");print a[2],a[3],a[4],$0}' file.txt | sort -n -k1 -k2 -k3 | cut -d ' ' -f 4-
```

I am using `split()` to split field 5 on underscores into array `a[]` and then taking elements 2, 3 and 4 (which should be year, month and day and pre-pending them to the front of the entire original record. Then I sort by the date at the start and remove the date.

Try this to see how it works:

```
awk -F';' '{split($5,a,"_");print a[2],a[3],a[4],$0}' file.txt
```

Comment: it was almost working, i didn't knew this split() function with awk thanks a lot will be usefull. I choosed the other solution since it allows me to choose date a bit more precisely than this with your method, though it was i nice idea thanks !